# Adding something to Twitch bot

Tags: python, bots, twitch

So I have looked up some vids and made one of those simple twitch bots that can handle triggers.

Now I made a trigger when a normal bot says "Welcome to the...." that it sends a message. I would like to add the names etc, and was wondering if this is possible.

Or is it possible to read the Twitch notification instead of the bot trigger (so the message without user name like '| name just subscribed wit ha $4.99 sub!')

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider reading [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/2ims79/please_i_beg_you_turn_off_the_auto_welcome_on/) reddit post before continuing your development.

However, [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNOBk_id22bwQiFrmoKcfzz3NX4gKkz5a) three part video series is a great reference tutorial which will give you good foundations on how to make a simple python based twitch bot.